# Prove that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $k\leq x$.

Tags: solution-verification, integers, upper-lower-bounds

In some earlier work, I proved that any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound.

I now want to prove that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $k\leq x$.

**Attempted proof**

Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that no such integer $k$ exists.

Then for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $a>x$. Thus, $x$ is a lower bound for $\mathbb{Z}$.

By the theorem I proved earlier, $\mathbb{Z}$ therefore has a greatest lower bound. Let's call it $\alpha$.

This means that $\alpha+1/2$ is not a lower bound, and thus, there exists some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha<b<\alpha+1/2$.

This means that $b-1$ is an integer less than $\alpha$, and hence, we have a contradiction.

---

Is this proof sufficient?

Comment: Do you feel any need of further clarification?

Comment: There’s one small error: since $\alpha+\frac12$ is not a lower bound, there is some $b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\alpha\color{red}{\le}b<\alpha+\frac12$. (The greatest lower bound could be an integer.) This doesn’t affect the final step, and the proof is otherwise just fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, of course. :)